# Parallel and perpendicular symbol from Mathematica to $\LaTeX$

Tags: latex

I want to get the following expression from *Mathematica* to $\LaTeX$:

\begin{bmatrix}
E_{\parallel} \\ E_{\perp}
\end{bmatrix}

I have tried to use inbuilt 'symbol' character from the special characters window but get an error:

[image: error]

So I thought maybe I can just type in \parallel and \perp so when I convert it to $\TeX$ it will be there and work, but I get different errors:

[image: more errors]

Any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following Mathematica construction translates to $\TeX$ just fine:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 e_{\bot } \\
 e_{\parallel } \\
\end{array}
\right)
```

Which looks like this in StackExchange's MathJax:

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 e_{\bot } \\
 e_{\parallel } \\
\end{array}
\right)$

The key issue is to enter the initial Mathematica construction correctly. That is done as follows.

The $\bot$ character is Mathematica's symbol `\[UpTee]` which is interpreted as the `UpTee` function which takes two arguments. This is part of the cause of the error messages you got. You haven't provided those.

You can type <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>null</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> for the first argument (which is nothing thanks to the null), followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>uT</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>null</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> again for the second argument.

The same goes for the $\parallel$ character, Mathematica's `DoubleVerticalBar` symbol and (undefined) function which can be entered as <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>||</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can just use

```
TeXForm@{{Subscript[E,\[Null]\[UpTee]\[Null]]},{Subscript[E,\[Null]\[DoubleVerticalBar]\[Null]]}}
```

to generate your TeX code. If you want square brackets you may want to change the `\left(` to `\left[` and `\right(` to `\right[`. Additionally, since Mathematica interprets `E` as Euler's number it ends up as a lower case e in the TeX code. You may want to change that back to an uppercase E manually afterwards, or use a `\[CapitalEpsilon]` in Mathematica. This gets translated as `E` in the TeX code.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thanks. I would have never figured that out.

Comment: I used this today - thanks!  Too bad it doesn't look so good in the notebook, but...

Comment: This answer fails to warn people that \bot and \perp sometimes have different results, and there's a good reason why they were intended to work that way: $$ \begin{align} & P\bot Q \\ \text{versus} \\ & P\perp Q \end{align} $$

Comment: Instead of `\[UpTee]` you can just use `\[Perpendicular]` or esc+perp+esc.